# Clarification of the proof of the Extreme Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

The following is an extract from Wade's Real Analysis book. I understood everything up to the highlighted part where what I see is it should be $|f(a)| > a$, from which I don't know how the contradiction follows.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $a$. Since $f$ is continuous, it follows that the sequence $(f(x_{n_k}))$ converges to $f(a)$, which is a real number. But on the other hand, $f(x_{n_k}) \geq n_k \geq k$ for all $k$, so the sequence $(f(x_{n_k}))$ cannot converge to a finite number.

Note: I think you may have thought that $f(x_{n_k}) \geq x_{n_k}$, but that's not what (7) says.